# Parse string based on recurring substring python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, substring

Input is a long substring, for brevity:

'This is just dummy header info \n Sometimes it's longer, sometimes shorter \n Date: 1/1/2000 \n Time: 16:00:30 \n Testname: meow \n Cycle: 1 \n 10 15 3 \n 3 69 23 \n 233 33.440 2 \n Channel: HBO \n Cycle: 1 \n 3 4 5 3 \n 2 3 4 5'

*Note, the floats are tab separated.

I would like to parse based on 'Cycle: '. Sometimes the string appears once, sometimes thrice. The important data is always after Cycle and ends with a blank new line. The result could be a list of listed data, for example:

[[10 15 3 3 60 23 233 33.440 2], [3 4 5 3 2 3 4 5]]

thanks in advance.

Edit

```
stringlist = re.split(r'\t+', rawsqlstring)
long_data = []
cycle_regex = re.compile('Cycle: ')

for el in stringlist:
    if channel_regex.match(el):
        break
for el in stringlist:
    if el.strip() == '\n':
        break
    long_data.append(el)
```

Comment: Do you know anything about Regex?

Comment: Yes, I've used it a few times. What would your approach be here, Eric?

Answer (score 1):

If `input` is a string

```
# Split string by newline character, filter out the ones which don't start with 'Cycle: '
# and cut off the 'Cycle' part
cycles = [sub[7:] for sub in input.split('\n') if sub.startswith('Cycle: ')]

# Parse those substrings into lists of ints
nums = [[int(n) for n in c.split(' ')] for c in cycles]
```

should work

Your data is hard to read as you have it posted, but playing with the terminating character(s) of `split` should yield results